# Wireless Network Adapter Problems on Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

Lately, I have been having issues with my wireless network adapter on my HP ProBook 4540s laptop running Windows 10 Pro x64. It is hard to point to one specific problem because I have had a number of issues.

For example, when I boot up my laptop, it will always connect to my home wireless without an issue, but sometimes I want my machine to use my WiFi extender's connection, but when I try switching to it, it will take forever to successfully connect to it even if the extender is one foot away from it. If I am lucky, it does eventually connect, but it more of than not, the end result is a failed attempt at connecting.

Another issue that I have experienced (the one shown in the GIF) is that when I turn off wireless on my laptop, reboot it, and then turn it on again, I am unable to connect to a network, as the "Connect" button does not respond properly. This issue varies from time to time. Sometimes, when you attempt to connect to a network, the WiFi connections panel will empty and return to "WiFi Disabled", but when the panel is reopened, they will all be present again, and other times, the "Connect" button issue happens.

I have tried simply toggling airplane mode on and off, both with and without a reboot, with no success. When that did not work, I completely uninstalled the Wireless Network Adapter and its drivers through the Device Manager and reinstalled them, and this did not work either.

I do not know if this could have any possible ties to the problems that I am having or not, but it may be worth noting that I run a VPN server from this computer, and around the same time that I noticed the issue with my wireless network adapter, my configuration for my VPN server in "Network Connections" in the Control Panel would occasionally be wiped out whenever I would restart the computer, and I would have to reconfigure it. This has not happened at all since I have reinstalled the drivers for my wireless adapter, but I do not know if there is a connection. In order to cover all bases, I have also run `sfc /scannow` to see if that would fix anything, and the result was a failed attempt to repair `opencl.dll`, but I do not know if this could be related to my problem given what is stated in [this article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/microsoft-acknowledges-system-file-checker-issue-in-windows-10-version-1511-502258.shtml).

I've completely run out of ideas concerning how to solve the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Windows 10 Wireless Network Adapter Problems]